# revolution slider, bullets strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, revolution-slider

I have a revolution slider carousel with a bullets navigation, that's the js configuration:

```
                var revapi2;
            tpj(document).ready(function() {
                if(tpj("#rev_slider_2_1").revolution == undefined){
                    revslider_showDoubleJqueryError("#rev_slider_2_1");
                }else{
                    revapi2 = tpj("#rev_slider_2_1").show().revolution({
                        sliderType:"carousel",
                        jsFileLocation:"libs/revolutionSlider/js/",
                        dottedOverlay:"none",
                         sliderLayout: "auto",
                        delay:9000,
                        navigation: {
                            keyboardNavigation:"off",
                            keyboard_direction: "horizontal",
                            mouseScrollNavigation:"off",
                            onHoverStop:"off",
                            arrows: {
                                style:"",
                                enable:true,
                                hide_onmobile:false,
                                hide_under:300,
                                hide_onleave:true,
                                hide_delay:200,
                                hide_delay_mobile:1200,
                                tmp:'',
                                left: {
                                    h_align:"left",
                                    v_align:"center",
                                    h_offset:30,
                                    v_offset:0
                                },
                                right: {
                                    h_align:"right",
                                    v_align:"center",
                                    h_offset:30,
                                    v_offset:0
                                }
                            },
                            touch:{
                             touchenabled:"off",
                             swipe_treshold : 75,
                             swipe_min_touches : 1,
                             drag_block_vertical:true,
                             swipe_direction:"horizontal"
                            }
                            ,
                            bullets: {
                                enable: true,
                                container:"slider",
                                hide_onmobile: false,
                                style: "ares",
                                hide_onleave: false,
                                direction: "horizontal",
                                h_align: "center",
                                v_align: "bottom",
                                h_offset: 20,
                                v_offset: 20,
                                space: 0,
                                rtl:false,
                                tmp: ''
                            }
                        },
                        carousel: {
                            horizontal_align: "center",
                            vertical_align: "center",
                            fadeout: "off",
                            maxVisibleItems: 3,
                            infinity: "on",
                            space: 0,
                            stretch: "off"
                        },
                        viewPort: {
                            enable:true,
                            outof:"pause",
                            visible_area:"80%"
                        },
                        responsiveLevels:[1240,1024,778,320],
                        gridwidth:[1240,1024,778,320],
                        gridheight:[600,600,500,300],
                        lazyType:"none",
                        parallax: {
                            type:"mouse",
                            origo:"slidercenter",
                            speed:2000,
                            levels:[2,3,4,5,6,7,12,16,10,50],
                        },
                        shadow:0,
                        spinner:"off",
                        stopLoop:"on",
                        stopLoop:"on",
                        stopAfterLoops:0,
                        stopAtSlide:1,
                        shuffle:"off",
                        autoHeight:"on",
                        hideThumbsOnMobile:"on",
                        hideSliderAtLimit:0,
                        hideCaptionAtLimit:0,
                        hideAllCaptionAtLilmit:0,
                        debugMode:false,
                        fallbacks: {
                            simplifyAll:"off",
                            nextSlideOnWindowFocus:"off",
                            disableFocusListener:false,
                        }
                    });


                }
            });
```

The bullets appears over my carousel but what i can see is a strange behaviour. During navigation beetween slides, the `.selected` class is applied correctly to the right index only at the beginning of the sliding process. At the end , when the slide is stopped and loaded, the `.selected` class is automatic cleared from the correct index and applied to the index 0. I'll try to be more clear in my explaination:

slider with 4 element **->** i click on the 3° bullet (the index 2)**->** my image begin to slide in the view e my 3° bullet is red (red is the color that i have assigned to the `.selected` class)**->** when the image slide animation is complete my 3° bullet return gray and my 1° bullet became red.

I have tried to intercept the event that cause this automatic change, but i have tried to log every events i have found in docs, and nothing is launched at the same time of my strange behaviour. It's a bug? How i can solve it?

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found any solution?